# Shows different information depending on the category Tribe events

Tags: php, events, categories, slug

it may be that at the end of an event, it displays different information depending on the category of the event using Tribe events plugin?

I’m triyng with this code, but i did not succed

```
<?php do_action('tribe_get_event_cat_slugs');
                if ( $slugs = ((array) 'charity') ) : ?>
                <p>If is 'charity' slug</p>
                <?php else : ?>
                <p>If is 'charity' slug</p>
        [contact-form-7 id="770" title="Inscrieri"]
<?php endif?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
<?php if ( $slugs = ((array) 'charity') ) {} ?>
```

Assigns `((array) 'charity') )` to `$slugs`. Be sure to read the documentation on [comparison operators](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).